# How do I specify a multi-column index with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, indexing

The goal here is have my complete database configuration and schema generation handled by fluent nhibernate.

Is there a way to to specify a multi-column index with Fluent nhibernate?

I understand that you can specify an index on a single property/column

like so :

```
mapping.Map(x => x.ItemDt).Index("IX_DataTransferLog_ItemDt");
```

how can I specify multiple columns?

If that isn't possible, is there a way to add raw SQL statements to a configuration that will be run after the schema is created/updated ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In XML-mappings this can be achieved by adding index with same name to all the properties that needs to be in the index:

```
<property name="Name" index="MyIndex" />
<property name="RunTimeInMinutes" index="MyIndex" />
```

Unfortunately I do not have any project currently using Fluent NHibernate that I could test this on, but I think this works in Fluent NHibernate the same way:

```
mapping.Map(x => x.Name).Index("MyIndex");
mapping.Map(x => x.RunTimeInMinutes).Index("MyIndex");
```

If this doesn't work, you can add the raw SQL required to create the index in `database-object` in mapping. NHibernate will execute the SQL when database is created using SchemaExport. I don't know if there is Fluent version for mapping database-objects but you can map `database-object` using XML and add the mapping file to Fluent NHibernate's configuration.

Comment: I've tested it and this works :

mapping.Map(x => x.Name).Index("MyIndex"); 
mapping.Map(x => x.RunTimeInMinutes).Index("MyIndex");

Comment: VERIFIED.  I scripted out the index and got:  USE [NhibernateDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_MyTable_ColumnA_And_ColumnB]    Script Date: 01/16/2012 17:26:57 ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MyTable_ColumnA_And_ColumnB] ON [dbo].[MyTable] 
(
 [ColumnA] ASC,
 [ColumnB] ASC
)
GO

Comment: this is correct and good, but is there a straightforward way to make the index unique?

Comment: found it - use UniqueKey("MyIndex") instead of Idex("MyIndex")

Comment: is there a possibility to create multiple index for one column (e.g. multi column index for column A and B, and another index for column A) via XML-mappings?